# How do I make this PHP/MYSQL code more efficient?

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP and I have a [test project](http://natzim.com/badidea/?):

I want to make the code more efficient as it takes some time to generate.
Thanks a lot, Nat

The code it uses is as follows:

```
    $result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `1` FROM `things` GROUP BY  `1` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1"));
    $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `2` FROM `things` GROUP BY  `2` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1"));
    $result3 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `3` FROM `things` GROUP BY  `3` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1"));
    $result4 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `4` FROM `things` GROUP BY  `4` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1"));

    echo $result1["1"];
    echo " ";
    echo $result2["2"];
    echo " ";
    echo $result3["3"];
    echo " ";
    echo $result4["4"];

    mysql_close($con);      
    ?>
```

Comment: 1. Combine the queries. 2. [**Stop using `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is the slowest possible way to write a query. If you want efficient queries, the first thing you'll need to do is work out a different method of getting random records.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html, good place to start.

Comment: I'm going to go and post this is codereview. I want to make this clear, I know most of you guys can't comprehend NOT wanting to learn the entire language, but it's not something I want to do, I just want to do small projects at a time. Expecting me to understand some of this is stupid. I was looking for someone to give me an updated code, not documentation to an updated msqli connections. I see that people have been downvoting me (or whatever you call it here) and I'm sorry I'm not as amazing as you.

Comment: You're being downvoted because your question is not a good fit for the Q&A format; which expects references or some research. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [Jon Skeet's guide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to ask a question.

Comment: As stated above, do not use the "mysql_*" PHP functions, they are deprecated as of PHP5.5 and will soon be removed. It has heaps of security flaws in it, and as such, I would strongly suggest using PDO.

However, you will still need to write SQL statements to read data from your MySQL database.

By the looks of things, your statements will return the following values:

[x,1] [x,2] [x,3] [x,4]

Where x is the same value in all of them. The use of RAND is superfluous. The use of GROUP BY is also superfluous. I think it might be a good idea to explain what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming good faith & cleaned up the code presented the best way possible using the methods you want to use.

```
<?

$count = 1;
$results = array();
for ($count; $count <= 4; $count++) {
  $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `%d` FROM `things` GROUP BY  `1` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", $count)
  $results[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
}

if (!empty($results)) {
  echo exlplode(" ", $results);
}

?>
```